# NivoSlider NivoControl Nav IE7 Not Displaying

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, nivo-slider

My nivoslider plugin works fine across all browsers and up to ie8/9 - however in IE 7 the slider works fine but i cant see the squares (nivocontrol nav) which indicates how many images there are in the slider. I've tried position:absolute and z-index's but i cant seem to get this working. Before it refused to work so i changed it from window.load to document.ready and that fixed 50% of the problem.

The website is http://www.sarahlayton.co.uk and if you look at it in IE8/9 you see the squares under the image slider and then ie7 its hidden. Im a little confused as to where i am going wrong?

Can anyone guide me please? really would be appreciated

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
        effect: 'random', // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
        slices: 15, // For slice animations
        boxCols: 8, // For box animations
        boxRows: 4, // For box animations
        animSpeed: 300, // Slide transition speed
        pauseTime: 6000, // How long each slide will show
        startSlide: 0, // Set starting Slide (0 index)
        directionNav: false, // Next & Prev navigation
        directionNavHide: false, // Only show on hover
        controlNav: true, // 1,2,3... navigation
        controlNavThumbs: false, // Use thumbnails for Control Nav
        controlNavThumbsFromRel: false, // Use image rel for thumbs
        controlNavThumbsSearch: '.jpg', // Replace this with...
        controlNavThumbsReplace: '_thumb.jpg', // ...this in thumb Image src
        keyboardNav: true, // Use left & right arrows
        pauseOnHover: true, // Stop animation while hovering
        manualAdvance: false, // Force manual transitions
        captionOpacity: 0.0, // Universal caption opacity
        prevText: 'Prev', // Prev directionNav text
        nextText: 'Next', // Next directionNav text
        beforeChange: function() { }, // Triggers before a slide transition
        afterChange: function() { }, // Triggers after a slide transition
        slideshowEnd: function() { }, // Triggers after all slides have been shown
        lastSlide: function() { }, // Triggers when last slide is shown
        afterLoad: function() { } // Triggers when slider has loaded
       });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I had the same problem. Slider worked great, but the control nav links would not show in IE7. I do not yet know why, and after 4 hours working on it I am not sure I care anymore. But here is what worked for me:

1. Look for "text-indent:-9999px;" for ".nivo-controlNav a" class in your CSS - comment it out.
2. Edit the jquery.nivo.slider.js - line 165 and take out the HTML in the a tag, basically make it look like:

   ```
   vars.controlNavEl.append('<a class="nivo-control" rel="'+ i +'"></a>');
   ```

That worked for me with no issues I can find so far. Hope it helps you.

Comment: 67 lines long is the sliderpack.js file - cant find the vars.controlNavEl.append

Answer (score 3):

This fix worked for me (inside IE7 only css)

```
.nivo-controlNav a {
    text-indent: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
}
```

`text-indent: 0;` will get the position right, `font-size: 0;` is needed to hide the numbers and `line-height: 0;` is needed to hide the dots that appear on IE7 if font-size is 0